# I can not start Microsoft Visual Code on Ubuntu 22.04 anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I use Visual code version 1.85.1. Even after downgrading to version 1.79.2 Visual Code does not start. I neither get a message why I can not start Visual Code. Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why did you downgrade? Have you checked the logs? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: There are no logfiles of yesterday when I created this call. Today I can start Visual code again. Because Visual Code yesterday did even not start with older versions, I reinstalled the latest version (1.85.1). I use Visual Code on Ubuntu 22.04. Luckily my Visual Code is able to start again. Probably a restart was needed to let it work again.

Comment: Hello, it's called Visual Studio Code first of all. Use correct terms when asking here. Secondly, there's 0 reason to downgrade so much. VSCode is very customizable and there should be absolutel no need to go down to that.

Comment: Same here, I am using Ubuntu22.04 core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch. VSCode 1.85.1, had the issue, stuck in an empty white screen then the app was terminated after one or two minutes, rebooted my laptop, and VSCode could run, upgraded to 1.85.2 the issue came back. I guess I need to reboot again.

Comment: Maybe that is an ubuntu issue?

Comment: @Destroy666 Downgrading and try is not a bad idea, if you know VSCode runs fine in a lower version. Go back the previous version and keep working is better than staring at the blank screen and waiting for someone else to fix the issue :)